# Kotlin - inline functions with multiple parameters

Tags: kotlin

I can define an inline function in Kotlin with:

```
inline fun func(a: () -> Unit, b: () -> Unit){
    a()
    b()
}
```

But how do I call this function?

For a normal inline function with only one parameter, I would use:

```
func {
    doSomething()
}
```

Is there a similar syntax for functions with more than one inline parameter?

Comment: You just put the first (at least) lambda inside parentheses, just like any other argument.

Comment: The way you call the function doesn't depend on whether it's inline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the last function parameter is passed outside the call operator.
For example:

```
fun foo(a: () -> Unit, b: () -> Unit)

foo({ println("hello") }) {
    println("world")
}
```

The other function parameters are just passed in the normal argument list inside the parenthesis, the last can *optionally* be moved outside of those parenthesis as is done with most calls.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to achieve this. 
Probably the nicest is to use a [bound function reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#bound-function-and-property-references-since-11) for the parameters before the last one:

```
fun foo(){
    func(::foo){foo()}
    //this also works:
    func(::foo, ::foo)
    //or place the other call within parentheses in a lambda. (you can only put the last lambda behind the method call.
    func( { foo() } ){foo()}
}

inline fun func(a: () -> Unit, b: () -> Unit){
    a()
    b()
}
```

If you want to call an objects method just place that objects name in front of the `::`

```
class Bar {
    val baz = Baz()

    fun foo() {
        func(baz::func2, ::foo)
    }

    fun func(a: () -> Unit, b: () -> Unit) {
        a()
        b()
    }
}

class Baz{
    fun func2(){}
}
```